# MySQL Recordset SUM() GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, recordset

I have two tables with the following entries:

TABLE 1
tblcategories

id category
1 Architect
2 Engineer
3 Project Manager

TABLE 2
tblpayments

id / categoryid / payment
1 / 1 / 100
2 / 2 / 150
3 / 2 / 50
4 / 1 / 200
5 / 1 / 50

Current my recordset sql looks like this:

SELECT tblcategories.id, tblcategories.category, SUM(tblpayments.payment) AS total
FROM tblcategories, tblpayments
WHERE (tblcategories.id = tblpayments.category) 
GROUP BY tblcategories.id

Which gives me the following result:

Record / Id / category / total
 
1 / 1 / Architect / 350 
2 / 2 / Engineer / 200

However, I would like the following result:

Record / Id / category / total
 
1 / 1 / Architect / 350 
2 / 2 / Engineer / 200
3 / 3 / Project Manager / 0

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT cat.id, cat.category, SUM(pay.payment) AS total 
FROM tblcategories cat LEFT JOIN tblpayments pay
    ON cat.id = pay.category
GROUP BY cat.id
```